# Magento 1: media library manager?

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm a newbie of Magento 1.

Is there a way to upload and/or delete images from media folder and its children? I mean a media library manager like wordpress' one.

[image]

So the question is: is there a media images manager? Or have I to develop one?

I've searched in admin but I can't find anything.

Comment: There is no any media manager extension/module in magento 1/2 you need to develop custom module or if you are wanting to delete all images goto pub/media and delete specific images safely.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free module that support clean image for Magento 1.9, you can use it to clean your images: https://github.com/fballiano/openmage-image-cleaner

Features:

- Identify and remove orphan category images (reading data from the default "image" attribute and all custom attributes of type "image").
- Identify and remove orphan product images (reading data from media_gallery).
- Identify and remove orphan WYSIWYG images and files (reading used images/files from cms_block, cms_page, core_email_template tables and all /skin/frontend CSS files).
- Check before delete: you can review (and download) the identified images before removing them.
- Possibility to blacklist folders and/or files (with wildcard support) not to ever identify them as orphans.
- Possibility to flush media/import, media/tmp, var/export, var/importexport.
- Compatible with Magento 1.9, OpenMage 19 and OpenMage 20 on PHP >= 7.4.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I didn't know this module, but I mean a simple media manager like Wordpress' one.